# Is there any way vim can autocomplete methods and classes from PyQt or PySide?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, pyqt, pyside

I find myself needing to refer to the documentation a lot simply because I can't remember the name of a method or class. Has anyone come across a way to autocomplete these packages while editing in vim?

Answer (score 1):

[Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) parses Python source and integrates well with vim.  Just build a tags file from your library or libraries of choice and point VIM to your tag file with:

```
set tags=<tags path>
```

This will only work if "t" is in your option complete string.  Check this with `set cpt?`